# класс set с++ не могу понять функцию count();

Tags: c++

```
    int n, k;
        cin >> n >> k;
        set<int> el;
        vector<int> ans;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            int x;
            cin >> x;
            if (!el.count(x)) {
                ans.push_back(i);
                el.insert(x);
            }
        }

не могу понять,что тут делает функция el.count();?
```

Comment: Определяет, есть ли уже такое значение в множестве. Манера странная и неэффективная, но встречается.

Comment: Я б сделал `if (el.insert(x).second) {ans.push_back();}`, должно быть немного быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

Ищет в контейнере элементы, эквивалентные val, и возвращает количество совпадений.

Поскольку все элементы в контейнере набора уникальны, функция может возвращать только 1 (Если элемент найден) или ноль (в противном случае).

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/count/

Ну да,по сути просто проверка есть ли число в множестве или нет